# Is it possible to have a keyword argument named `class` or other reserved name in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

A lot of Rails tag helpers (e.g. [content_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag) etc.) use a hash option parameter named `class` to specify a HTML class.

```
content_tag(:div, content_tag(:p, "Hello world!"), class: "strong")
```

For new code I would like to use keyword arguments, but is that possible when one of them is a language keyword?

e.g. for a hypothetical `link_tag`.

```
def link_tag(url, class: nil)
  html = ''
  html << '<a href="' << url << '"'
  html << ' class="' << class << '"' if class
  ...


def link_tag(url, opts={})
  html = ''
  html << '<a href="' << url << '"'
  html << ' class="' << opts[:class] << '"' if opts[:class]
  ...
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. In Ruby, it is conventional to use `klass` or `clazz` instead.

Comment: does Rails have a convention, or will they just keep using "opts={}"?

Comment: I thought of a way to do this. It's ugly though. Putting it as a full answer.

Comment: Your second form is fine.  Were you encountering some kind of error or were you wondering if this was best practice?

Comment: No, error, just for new functions `a: default, b: nil`, etc. seems a lot tidier than `opts` and you must read the doc comment to see what it may contain.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Kind of. You have to avoid confusing the Ruby lexer by avoiding the literal keyword in your code, though. In Ruby 2.2+, you can get around it with `binding.local_variable_get`:

```
def link_tag(url, class: nil)
  format('<a href="%s" class="%s"></a>', url, binding.local_variable_get(:class))
end

link_tag("http://stackoverflow.com", class: "fancy")
# => "<a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\" class=\"fancy\"></a>"
```

This isn't really a very clean way of doing things, though, and is likely to be confusing. I would just try to rename my arguments to not conflict with the language if I were to use keyword args, though (ie, `css_class` or the conventional `klass`, etc).

Comment: This is good for situations where others don't care about the implementation, they're not responsible for it, and you're just trying to create a clean, coherent API.

Comment: I believe, there is a discussion about this on the Ruby bug tracker, about maybe adding some optional sigil to local variables, or a general way of escaping keywords (akin to Scala's use of backticks).

Comment: @tadman, yep, keeping the existing convention is the bigger issue than if I even use keywords at all right now :)

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag indeed, after some digging I found this: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13207